# How to configure LDAP in ApacheDS to use uid for authentication?

Tags: ldap, apache-ds

When adding a new user under the `dc=example,dc=com` using Apache Directory Studio, I have this tree structure:

```
dc=example,dc=com
|-- ou = engineering
     |-- cn = Lawrence K.H Loh+o=IKEA+sn=Loh+uid=lawrence+displayName=Lawrence
```

Below is the attribute list for the `cn`.

1. objectClass = inetOrgPerson
2. objectClass = organizationalPerson
3. objectClass = person
4. objectClass = top
5. cn = Lawrence K.H Loh
6. sn = Loh
7. displayName = Lawrence
8. o = IKEA
9. uid = lawrence
10. userPassword = SSHA hashed password

There is this error `LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry` when I connect this entry through `uid=lawrence,ou=engineering,dc=example,dc=com`. But it is working fine if I'm using this `cn=Lawrence K.H Loh+o=IKEA+sn=Loh+uid=lawrence+displayName=Lawrence,ou=engineering,dc=example,dc=com`. May I know how can I switch to `uid=lawrence` instead of the long name for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that particular object, it's unlikely that you can. LDAP is looking for you to bind with the *distinguished name* (DN) of the object, and the primary attribute in this case is `cn`. This is a deliberate design decision because there is no guarantee that any given attribute of objects within a container will be unique other than the one that is associated with their DN.

This will not stop services from being able to search your directory and determine that `uid=lawrence` is associated with that particular DN (and thus being able to find any other attributes needed off of that object), but any calls that explicitly need to be run against a DN can only be run against the primary attribute.

This isn't to say that there aren't ways that you can avoid specifying a DN. Implementing SASL authentication and defining a map between SASL IDs and DNs comes to mind. But within the context of your question, no, you cannot switch to using a non-primary attribute of the DN you're authenticating to in place of the DN.